# Repaint Not Always Working

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, paint

I have the location and previous location of my character repainted every time it moves. This works, most of the time. Occasionally and seemingly randomly, the image of the character will be left behind, and not repainted, even after continued movement.

Class that deals with Graphics and Character Movement:

```
public class GameState extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
Container contentPane=this.getContentPane();
Graphics bufferGraphics;

int characterX=463;
int characterY=486;
int oldCharacterX=463;
int oldCharacterY=486;
int xAxis;
int yAxis;
Image characterNorth = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterNorth.jpg").getImage();
Image characterEast = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterEast.jpg").getImage();
Image characterSouth = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterSouth.jpg").getImage();
Image characterWest = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/characterWest.jpg").getImage();
Image brickWall = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/brickWall.jpg").getImage();
Image brickFloor = CustomImages.createImageIcon("Images/brickFloor.jpg").getImage();
Image character=characterNorth;
boolean pressed=false;

ArrayList<RoomState> map = new ArrayList<RoomState>();
RoomState currentRoom = new RoomState();
RoomState currentRoomState=new RoomState();

GameState() {
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 1680, 1050);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
}

public void move(int x, int y) { //Check Move
    currentRoomState=currentRoomState.MoveToNextRoom(true, false, false, false);
    currentRoomState=currentRoomState.MoveToNextRoom(false, true, false, false);
    currentRoomState=currentRoomState.MoveToNextRoom(false, false, true, false);
    currentRoomState=currentRoomState.MoveToNextRoom(false, false, false, true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) { //Graphics
    for(xAxis=58;xAxis<=858;xAxis=xAxis+50) {
        for(yAxis=81;yAxis<=881;yAxis=yAxis+50) {
            g.drawImage(brickFloor,xAxis,yAxis,null);
        }
        yAxis=31;
    }
    for(xAxis=8;xAxis<958;xAxis=xAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }
    yAxis=931;
    for(xAxis=8;xAxis<=908;xAxis=xAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }
    xAxis=8;
    for(yAxis=81;yAxis<=881;yAxis=yAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }
    xAxis=908;
    for(yAxis=81;yAxis<=881;yAxis=yAxis+50) {
        g.drawImage(brickWall,xAxis,yAxis,null);
    }

    if(currentRoom.northDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,458,31,null);
    }
    if(currentRoom.eastDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,908,481,null);
    }
    if(currentRoom.southDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,458,931,null);
    }
    if(currentRoom.westDoor) {
        g.drawImage(brickFloor,8,481,null);
    }

    g.drawImage(character,characterX,characterY,null);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) { //Character Rotation/Movement.
    if(pressed==false) {
        pressed=true;
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            if(character==characterNorth) {
                if(characterY>86 && characterX>13 && characterX<913) {
                    characterY=characterY-50;
                }else if(currentRoom.northDoor && characterX==463) {
                    oldCharacterY=characterY;
                    characterY=characterY-50;
                    if(characterY==-14) {
                        RoomState nextRoom = new RoomState();
                        nextRoom.southDoor = true;
                        nextRoom.rs_SouthDoor = currentRoom;
                        currentRoom.rs_NorthDoor = nextRoom;
                        map.add(nextRoom);
                        currentRoom = nextRoom;
                        nextRoom = null;
                        characterX=463;
                        characterY=936;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                character=characterNorth;
            }
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            if(character==characterWest && characterY>36 && characterY<926) {
                if(characterX>63) {
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX-50;
                }else if(currentRoom.westDoor && characterY==486) {
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX-50;
                    if(characterX==-37) {
                        RoomState nextRoom = new RoomState();
                        nextRoom.eastDoor = true;
                        nextRoom.rs_EastDoor = currentRoom;
                        currentRoom.rs_WestDoor = nextRoom;
                        map.add(nextRoom);
                        currentRoom = nextRoom;
                        nextRoom = null;
                        characterX=913;
                        characterY=486;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                character=characterWest;
            }
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            if(character==characterSouth) {
                if(characterY<871 && characterX>13 && characterX<913) {
                    oldCharacterY=characterY;
                    characterY=characterY+50;
                }else if(currentRoom.southDoor && characterX==463) {
                    oldCharacterY=characterY;
                    characterY=characterY+50;
                    if(characterY==986) {
                        RoomState nextRoom = new RoomState();
                        nextRoom.northDoor = true;
                        nextRoom.rs_NorthDoor = currentRoom;
                        currentRoom.rs_SouthDoor = nextRoom;
                        map.add(nextRoom);
                        currentRoom = nextRoom;
                        nextRoom = null;
                        characterX=463;
                        characterY=36;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                character=characterSouth;
            }
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            if(character==characterEast && characterY>36 && characterY<926) {
                if(characterX<848) {
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX+50;
                }else if(currentRoom.eastDoor && characterY==486) {
                    oldCharacterX=characterX;
                    characterX=characterX+50;
                    if(characterX==963) {
                        RoomState nextRoom = new RoomState();
                        nextRoom.westDoor = true;
                        nextRoom.rs_WestDoor = currentRoom;
                        currentRoom.rs_EastDoor = nextRoom;
                        map.add(nextRoom);
                        currentRoom = nextRoom;
                        nextRoom = null;
                        characterX=13;
                        characterY=486;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                 character=characterEast;
            }
        }
        repaint(oldCharacterX,oldCharacterY,40,40);
        repaint(characterX,characterY,40,40);
        }
    }

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) { //Prevents Holding Down Keys.
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        pressed=false;
    }
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        pressed=false;
    }
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        pressed=false;
    }
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        pressed=false;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
}
```

}

Comment: Way too many magic numbers!

Comment: `void paint(Graphics g)` doesn't call `super.paint(g);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set either `oldCharacterX` or `oldCharacterY` in your `keyPressed()` method, depending on which key is pressed.  Yet, sometimes you set both the X and Y coordinates!  It looks like the one of the sets should be a no-op, but why take the risk?

Instead you should unconditionally set both at the top of the function.  Then, you can remove the redundant settings of oldCharacterX/Y in each keypress case.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if(pressed==false) {
        pressed=true;
        oldCharacterX = characterX;
        oldCharacterY = characterY;

        //... keypress handling ...

        if (oldCharacterX != characterX  ||  oldCharacterY != characterY) {
            // Only need to repaint old position if it is different from the new
            repaint(oldCharacterX, oldCharacterY, 40, 40);
        }
        repaint(characterX, characterY, 40, 40);
    }
}
```